# give video player hexagonal shape

Tags: html, video, html5-video, video-processing

I'm looking for a video player that can be shaped like a hexagon (or other shapes)
it seems not possible with youtube, is there a flash or html 5 player that can give that shape to a video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this technique using masks to hide parts of the video player:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/AddingCSSStyles/AddingCSSStyles.html

Much of this is specific to WebKit (Safari and Chrome) so you may be limited in browser support.